# @font-face kit Preloader

Tags: javascript, html, fonts, font-face, webfonts

I am using [Font Squirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator)
to generate a custom Icon font file for my site. Is there a way to preload the  font before rendering the page in Internet Explorer 9 as well as other browsers.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's [link prefetching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_prefetching). This might work in IE 9.

If all else fails, [this](http://paulirish.com/2009/fighting-the-font-face-fout/) article might help.